# R Draw All Axis Labels (Prevent Some From Being Skipped)

Tags: r, plot

When I manually add the following labels with (`axis(1, at=1:27, labels=labs[0:27])`):

```
> labs[0:27]
 [1] "0\n9.3%"  "1\n7.6%"  "2\n5.6%"  "3\n5.1%"  "4\n5.7%"  "5\n6.5%"  "6\n7.3%"  "7\n7.6%"  "8\n7.5%"  "9\n7%"    "10\n6.2%" "11\n5.2%"
[13] "12\n4.2%" ........
```

I get the following:

[image]

How do I force all labels to be drawn so 1,3,5,6, and 11 are not skipped? (also, for extra credit, how do I shift the whole thing down a few pixels?)

Comment: Do you really want to include 0 in your indexing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

?axis tells you that:

> The code tries hard not to draw overlapping tick labels, and so will omit labels where they would abut or overlap previously drawn labels. This can result in, for example, every other tick being labelled. (The ticks are drawn left to right or bottom to top, and space at least the size of an ‘m’ is left between labels.)

Play with `cex.axis` so that labels are small enough to fit without overlapping

```
labs <-c("0\n9.3%","1\n7.6%","2\n5.6%","3\n5.1%","4\n5.7%","5\n6.5%","6\n7.3%",
         "7\n7.6%","8\n7.5%","9\n7%", "10\n6.2%","11\n5.2%","12\n4.2%",12:27)
plot(1:27,xaxt = "n")
axis(side=1, at=1:27, labels=labs[0:27],cex.axis=0.35)
```

If you widen you graph (manually by dragging or programmatically), you can increase the size of your labels.

Comment: Thanks a lot. cex.axis greatly helped

Comment: A note: my x-axis was comprised of character strings, so I fiddled with `cex.names` instead and it gave me the desired output at the end.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to force all labels to display, even when they are very close or overlapping, you can "trick" R into displaying them by adding odd and even axis labels with separate calls to the `axis` function, as follows:

```
labs <-c("0\n9.3%","1\n7.6%","2\n5.6%","3\n5.1%","4\n5.7%","5\n6.5%","6\n7.3%",
         "7\n7.6%","8\n7.5%","9\n7%", "10\n6.2%","11\n5.2%","12\n4.2%",13:27)
n=length(labs)
plot(1:28, xaxt = "n")
axis(side=1, at=seq(1,n,2), labels=labs[seq(1,n,2)], cex.axis=0.6)
axis(side=1, at=seq(2,n,2), labels=labs[seq(2,n,2)], cex.axis=0.6)
```

[image]

You can play with `cex.axis` to get the text size that you want. Note, also, that you may have to adjust the number of values in `at=` and/or `labels=` so that they are equal.

I agree with @PLapointe and @joran that it's generally better not to tamper with R's default behavior regarding overlap. However, I've had a few cases where axis labels looked fine even when they weren't quite a full "m-width" apart, and I hit on the trick of alternating odd and even labels as a way to get the behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Although there are some good answers here, the OP didn't want to resize the labels or change anything about the plot besides fitting all of the axis labels.  It's annoying, since often there appears to be plenty of room to fit all of the axis labels.

Here's another solution.  Draw the plot without the axis, then add ticks with empty labels.  Store the positions of the ticks in an object, so then you can go through each one and place it in the correct position on the axis.

`plot(1:10, 1:10, yaxt = "n")
axis_ticks = axis(2, axTicks(2), labels = rep("", length(axTicks(2))))
for(i in axis_ticks) axis(2, i)`

Answer (score 3):

@PLapointe just posted what I was going to say, but omitted the bonus answer.

Set `padj = 0.5` in `axis` to move the labels down slightly.

Comment: Other alternative is to make the labels perpendicular with
```plot(..., las=2)``` or ```par(las=2); plot(...)```

Comment: +1 for the previous rotate axis solution. A note about the above, in case you are using `plot(...,axis=FALSE,...)` and `axis(1,....)`, then add the option to axis: `axis(1,...,las=2)`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps draw and label one tick at a time, by calling `axis` repeatedly using `mapply`...

For example, consider the following data:

```
x = runif(100)*20
y = 10^(runif(100)*3)
```

The formula for `y` might look a bit odd; it gives random numbers distributed across three orders of magnitude such that the data will be evenly distributed on a plot where the y axis is on a log scale.  This will help demonstrate the utility of `axTicks()` by calculating nice tick locations for us on a logged axis.

By default:

```
plot(x, y, log = "y")
```

returns:

[image]

Notice that 100 and 1000 labels are missing.

We can instead use:

```
plot(x, y, log = "y", yaxt = "n")
mapply(axis, side = 2, at = axTicks(2), labels = axTicks(2))
```

which calls `axis()` once for each tick location returned by `axTicks()`, thus plotting one tick at a time.  The result:

[image]

What I like about this solution is that is uses only one line of code for drawing the axis, it prints exactly the default axis R would have made, except all ticks are labeled, and the labels don't go anywhere when the plot is resized:

[image]

I can't say the axis is useful in the resized example, but it makes the point about axis labels being permanent!

For the first (default) plot, note that R will recalculate tick locations when resizing.

For the second (always labeled) plot, the number and location of tick marks are not recalculated when the image is resized.  The axis ticks calculated by `axTicks` depend upon the size of the display window when the plot is first drawn.

If you want want to force specific tick locations, try something like:

```
plot(x, y, log = "y", yaxt = "n")
mapply(axis, side = 2, at = c(1,10,100, 1000), labels = c("one", "ten", "hundred", "thousand"))
```

which yields:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`axis()` includes a `gap.axis` parameter that controls when labels are omitted.  Setting this to a very negative number will force all labels to display, even if they overlap.

The `padj` parameter of `axis()` controls the y offset whilst plotting an individual axis.

`par(mgp = c(3, 2, 0)` will adjust the position of all axis labels for the duration of a plotting session: the second value (here `2`, default `1`) controls the position of the labels.

```r
# Set axis text position, including for Y axis
par(mgp = c(3, 2, 0))

# Plot
plot(1:12, 1:12, log = 'x', ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE)

# Some numbers not plotted:
axis(1, 1:12)

# All numbers plotted, with manual offset
axis(1, 1:12, gap.axis = -100, padj = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to stagger the labels and get them to print without losing some. I created two sets of ticks showing second set below the other to make it look as if it staggers.

```
xaxis_stagger = function(positions,labels) {
  odd=labels[seq(1,length(labels),2)]
  odd_pos=positions[seq(1,length(positions),2)]
  even=labels[seq(2,length(labels),2)]  
  even_pos=positions[seq(2,length(positions),2)]
  axis(side=1,at=odd_pos,labels=odd)
  axis(side=1,at=even_pos,labels=even,padj=1.5)
}
```

So you give the positions where you want the ticks to be and the labels for those ticks and this would then re-organise it into two sets of axis and plot them on the original plot. Original plot would be done with xaxt="n".