# Why is one number missing with barplot?

Tags: r

My code

```
c1 <- c(60,198,102,134,80,94,124,151,102,111,210,118)
names(c1) <- 1:length(c1)

png("s10.png", width=5,height=3.5,units="in",res=800)
barplot(c1, main = "number of points per cluster", 
        col = "dark blue")
op <- par(cex=.64)
par(op)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Why is 11 missing?I need good picture because I need to submit major revision for one respected journal.

Comment: Your image isn't wide enough - shrink the axis labels or increase the width of the png.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes,that was the problem,thanks!

Comment: Or use [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11301350/496488) if you want to prevent some values from being skipped even when R thinks they're too close together.