# showing different scaling in y axis when plotting two line graph in one plot

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot two different graph in one plot. But, the labeling in y axis is overlapping even though is the labeling is same. Here is my data-

[data file 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9cF34iSt6PAMzQtc2pnS1dhc1E)

[data file 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9cF34iSt6PAMV91RVFITkxlMnM)

I used the following code-

```
plot(`2000_svm_movie`,type="o",col="blue",xlab="Training Years",ylab="Performances", axes=FALSE)
axis(1,at=seq(2000,2014,by=1),las=2)
axis(2,at=seq(78,82,by=1),las=1)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(`2000_random_movie`,type="o",col="red",xlab="Training Years",ylab="Performances", axes=FALSE)
axis(1,at=seq(2000,2014,by=1),las=2)
axis(2,at=seq(78,86,by=1),las=1)
```

I want Y axis will be labeled  like (78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86). How can I do this? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your data, but so far I understand you want something like this?

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(2007, 2014), ylim=c(78,86), xlab="Training Years", ylab="Performances")
axis(side=2, at=c(78:86), labels=c(78:86))


x1 <- c(2007:2014)
y1 <- runif(8,78,86)

lines(x1, y1, col="blue")
points(x1,y1, col="blue")

y2 <- runif(8,78,86)
lines(x1, y2, col="red")
points(x1,y2, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: The point's are not in a right position. Red dot at 2007 will be at position 79.06 and green will be at 81.32. Moreover when i scale it to 2000-2014, nothing is appearing

Comment: Thats right the points are not at the good position, I just use random data. You can use your data insteed or post your data that we just can copy it.

Comment: Ah, it's almost working. Thanks. But, in both axis, x and y, label is skipped one after one. like -78,80,82.... How to make all the label appear?

Comment: You are welcome. I add some thing in my post up...maybe that already help other wise you can use the `text()` function - with this you can also rotate the labels...further you can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688854/r-draw-all-axis-labels-prevent-some-from-being-skipped) for solutions