# Why ACF not plotting lags

Tags: r, time-series

Hi does anyone know why my ACF is not plotting my lag max when for my time series? You can use the airpassenger data in R for this question.

My code is:

```
acf(z.t, lag.max = 40, main = expression(paste("acf of Z"[t])))
```

and I'm getting

[image: this]

but want have 1-40 on the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you but could you describe how in markdown language you reformatted this posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is a time series by month. Forty lags spans a range of 40 months, or 3.33 years. The time unit on the x-axis is denominated in years and you're seeing lags of 0 to 40 months in the graph.

As another example, if you run `acf(AirPassengers, lag.max=12)` you can see that the x-axis has lags from 0 to 12 months and the axis is labeled from zero to 1 year.

[image]

You can relabel the axis if you wish. For example:

```
mx=40
acf(AirPassengers, lag.max=mx, xaxt="n", xlab="Lag (months)")
axis(1, at=0:mx/12, labels=0:mx)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add anything to plot by even digits?

Comment: In the posted example, which digits actually show up depends on the size of the plot as rendered. If you make the plot larger, more digits will appear. If you make it smaller, fewer will appear. You can also make the labels smaller and more labels will be printed. For example, try `axis(1, at=0:mx/12, labels=0:mx, cex.axis=0.5)`. If you only want tick marks at even lags: `axis(1, at=seq(0,mx,2)/12, labels=seq(0,mx,2), cex.axis=1)`.

Comment: If you want tick marks at every lag, but you want labels only every other lag, then you can make every other label blank: `axis(1, at=0:mx/12, labels=c(rbind('', seq(0,mx,2)))[-1], cex.axis=0.7)`

Comment: The discussion in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688854/r-draw-all-axis-labels-prevent-some-from-being-skipped/11301350#11301350) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the units of the axis are in seasonal units (periods), not time units.

`frequency(AirPassengers)` gives 12, so monthly. The axis in your plot goes to ~3.33, which is precisely 40 / 12.

You can get the values to generate your own plot from `acf` with `x = acf(AirPassengers, lag.max = 40)` and getting `x$acf` and `x$lag`.

You can also do:

```
library(forecast)
Acf(AirPassengers, lag.max = 40)
```