# Labelling every category in R bar plot / box plot: `gap.axis` equivalent?

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting bar plots and box plots using `boxplot` and `barplot` in R, and space is tight.  I every bar / box to be labelled visibly, but R automatically hides labels that it reckons will make the display too cramped.

`axis()` has the parameter `gap.axis`.  Is there an equivalent for `boxplot` and `barplot`?

Plotting `barplot(..., axes = FALSE); axis(1, gap.axis = 0)` doesn't work because the position of the *x* axis doesn't correspond to the position of bars.

Reproducible example:

```r
boxplot(matrix(1:100, 10, 10), cex.axis = 2)
barplot(setNames(1:10, 1:10), cex.names = 2)
```

Comment: Do we want to show every x and y axis tick labels? in your example 1,2,3,..10? Maybe see this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/8688854/680068

Comment: That's right.  The example you linked is great for `plot()`, but doesn't help for `barplot()` or `boxplot()`.

Comment: Another related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9981929/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R 4.1.0, `barplot()` passes `gap.axis` is passed with the `...` to `axis()`, producing the required effect.  To suppress the warnings resulting from `gap.axis` also being passed to other plotting functions ([reported](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18108) as a bug), use:

```r
suppressWarnings(barplot(setNames(1:10, 1:10),
                         cex.names = 2, gap.axis = -10))
```

[Edited:]
As of R4.1.0-patched80484, `gap.axis` is natively supported by `boxplot()`, thanks to [Martin Maechler](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18109).

As a workaround in older versions of R, use:

```r
dat <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
boxplot(dat, axes = FALSE)
axis(1, seq_len(ncol(dat)), colnames(dat),
     cex.axis = 2, gap.axis = -10)
```